# How to split, map, and join in Bash?

Tags: regex, bash

I want to create a simple regular expression to match some files. The command `npm ls --dev --parseable` prints out a bunch of files, for example:

```
/Users/chetcorcos/code/dev-tool/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/tough-cookie
/Users/chetcorcos/code/dev-tool/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/tunnel-agent
/Users/chetcorcos/code/dev-tool/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/rimraf
/Users/chetcorcos/code/dev-tool/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/rimraf/node_modules/glob
/Users/chetcorcos/code/dev-tool/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/rimraf/node_modules/glob/node_modules/inflight
/Users/chetcorcos/code/dev-tool/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/rimraf/node_modules/glob/node_modules/inflight/node_modules/wrappy
```

I want to get back a string that looks something like this:

`tough-cookie|tunnel-agent|rimraf|inflight|wrappy`

To get this, I want to "split by newline, map over basename, and join with a pipe". In JavaScript with Ramdajs, I'd so something like this:

`R.pipe(R.split('\n'), R.map(R.split('/')), R.map(R.nth(-1)), R.join('|'))`

Any ideas how to do something like this in bash? Whats the idiomatic way of doing this?

Comment: In general -- if you want a one-liner, rather than an answer focused on correctness over terseness, you should be over at Code Golf rather than StackOverflow.

Comment: ...short form: It's possible to work with conventional functional-programming primitives in bash, but need to build them yourself; we're talking about 100 lines of library code or so.

Comment: I see. I'm just interested in whatever is the proper way to accomplish this in bash. Those are just the semantics I'm used to that seem intuitive.

Comment: They're intuitive for many other languages, but bash isn't one of them. If you want the best way to write this pipeline, rather than one that uses your primitives of choice, you might alter the question appropriately.

Comment: ok, whats the idiomatic way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bash doesn't have functional programming primitives built in. It's possible to build them with a hundred lines of code or so, but also not particularly worth it for this kind of use case.

---

Consider:

```
content=$(npm ls --dev --parseable | sed -e 's@.*/@@' | paste -s -d '|')
echo "$content"
```

...this routes the stdout of NPM into `sed`, telling it to replace everything up to the last slash in each line with an empty string, and then routing the stdout of `sed` into `paste`, using that to combine all lines into a single string with `|` separating them.

---

Alternately, to use no tools not built into bash itself (other than your data source, `npm`):

```
#!/bin/bash
# note that this requires bash 4.0 or later
mapfile -t lines < <(npm ls --dev --parseable) # read content into array
lines=( "${lines[@]##*/}" )                    # trim everything prior to last / in each
(IFS='|'; printf '%s\n' "${lines[*]}")         # emit array as a single string with |s
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just pipe that thing to `awk` and have `awk` pick off the last element:

```
 npm ls --dev --parseable | awk -F"/" '{output=output$(NF)"|"} END { sub(/[|]+$/, "", output); print output }'
```

That `awk` script will split incoming records by `/`, capture the last element `$(NF)` to variable `output` with a pipe to delimit, Then once complete, will strip the last pipe using `gsub` and spit the results out

Answer (score 1):

You already have a 'list' of strings, separated by '\n'.
Just map `basename` on each item (using xargs) - then you'll get list of basenames separated by '\n' plus final '\n'. Then replace each '\n' with '|' symbol:

```
anycmd | xargs -r -n1 basename | tr '\n' '|'
```

You may then remove last '|' by either sed or second xargs.

```
anycmd | xargs -r -n1 basename | tr '\n' '|' | sed 's/|$//'
```

or

```
anycmd | xargs -r -n1 basename | xargs | tr ' ' '|'
```